# After installing ImageMagick, I cannot use it from the commandline

Tags: imagemagick, macports

I installed ImageMagick using

```
$ sudo port install ImageMagick
```

However, when I run a basic command in a new terminal window, I get an error

```
$ convert logo.gif
-bash: convert: command not found
```

Why can't I run ImageMagick commands?

I've added ImageMagick to my path.  See below for a bash profile:

```
#~/.bash_profile
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.8.9"
```

Note, I removed the above from my bash profile when I applied my solution.

Comment: FYI convert takes two arguments, not one. I don't know how port works, but I would look to see if it installed the executables in your PATH. Also sometimes package managers don't rehash your shell's cached list of executables. This can be verified by logging out and logging back in, or depending on your shell a special built-in.

Comment: I've added it to my shell and logged out but and in but the command still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled macports and installed homebrew instead.  Then I installed ImageMagick with homebrew and it worked just fine.

I needed to use the command: `brew install imagemagick --build-from-source`.  The regular command gave me a different error